# Preparing CURL request with php

Tags: php, curl, webdav

I would like to have the following curl request generated using php CURL library for webdav.

curl -n -X MOVE "http://localhost/ocm/remote.php/webdav/dir1/subdir" -H "Destination: http://localhost/ocm/remote.php/webdav/dir1/"

Please help

Comment: Show us what have you done so far...

Comment: I would like to know how to create this request using php curl library

Answer (score 0):

Go through [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)..It shows all the curl option available to use in PHP along with examples...